# explanation about a Java implementation of radix sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I'm reading and learning about a Java implementation of radix sort, as shown below. It would be great if someone could clarify the logical meaning of `pointTo`, `index` and `globalPtr`.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity/editorial

```
private void radixSort0() {
    globalPtr = 0;
    Arrays.fill(bucketHead, -1);
    Arrays.fill(next, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int value = nr0[index[i]];
        if (bucketHead[value] == -1) bucketHead[value] = bucketTail[value] = globalPtr;
        else bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = globalPtr;
        pointTo[globalPtr++] = index[i];
    }

    int ptr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = bucketHead[i]; j != -1; j = next[j])
            index[ptr++] = pointTo[j];
}
```

Comment: donot post hackerrank problems for answers better try something  and post your code for some modifications. happy coding

Comment: Never, ever, immitate that style to name, (not-)comment, code, program. The easy part is `globalPtr`: the _next index to allocate_. The link to hackerrank requires log in - is the contents the same as [lydxlx's](https://github.com/zeyuanxy/hacker-rank/blob/master/algorithms/strings/string-similarity/Solution.Java)?

Comment: Thanks @greybeard, then what is the logical meaning of pointTo？

Comment: @greybeard, I am especially confused by this statement, `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = globalPtr`, why we cannot just use `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]]=index[i]`, not see too much values of `globalPtr`? Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: (Please state the [github link](https://github.com/zeyuanxy/hacker-rank/blob/master/algorithms/strings/string-similarity/Solution.Java) pertinent or not.) That part is _appending to the end of a singly linked list_ using an additional level of (de)indexing. I haven't really tried to figure out whether that is called for: many things used in `radixSort0` are pre-set or used outside. (If this was close  lydxlx's code, `globalPtr, pointTo, bucketHead, bucketTail`, and `next` could as well be local to radixSort0&1.) I'd be surprised if the base for this code wasn't from an algorithms textbook.

Comment: Thanks @greybeard, here is the code based for this code (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity/editorial), it will be great if you could help to comment, for line `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = globalPtr`, why we cannot just use `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]]=index[i]`, not see too much values of `globalPtr`? Thanks.

Comment: @greybeard, thanks for the response, I misunderstand your question. I reviewed the code in github link and it is the same as what I am posting. It will be appreciated if you could comment on why we cannot just use `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]]=index[i]`, and not using `pointTo` and `globalPrt`. Thanks.

Comment: (I will give the code some thought, probably after a night's sleep.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `radixSort0()` is not a complete radix sort. If your goal is to learn about radix sort, look elsewhere.
In both (needlessly duplicated) `radixSort` methods, `int[] next` is used to establish singly linked lists - using indexes instead of references, and -1 instead of null. (You can *not* just set `next[some_index_depending_on value]` to `index[i]` - there would be no lists.) The `int[] pointTo` would probably be more descriptively be named `value`. Think of `next&value` as linked lists, represented in an instance with two data members of type array, as an alternative to an array of instances with members `next&value`. `globalPtr` is the smallest index not yet allocated in that/those array/s.

(The blaring lack of comments in the code to follow is owing to my lack of understanding why anyone should try and construct a suffix array using this, or what the pieces of code contribute to that goal: feel free to correct&amend.)
Not even thinking about testing, the Java way of handling this might be

```
private void radixSortStep(int[]nr) {
    List<Integer> value[] = new List[M];
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        value[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);

    for (int i: indexes)
        value[nr[i]].add(i);

    int ptr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int val: value[i])
            indexes[ptr++] = val;
}
```

(with a bit of hand-waving about `M` (set to n+1) and `nr1` (initialise entries not copied from rank to `n`, not -1))

Comment: Thanks greybeard, working on learning your code. One more confusion about the github version of code, I reviewed the code in github link, and it will be appreciated if you could comment on why we cannot just use `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]]=index[i]`, and completely remove the usage of `pointTo` and `globalPrt`. I thought we are safe to use index[i] safely other than using pointTo/globalPtr to have another level of indirection. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I tried in the parenthesis: `next[]` and `bucketTail[]` are for `List` infrastructure, only `pointTo[]` holds (index-)values.

Comment: Hi greybeard, love your elegant implementation! Agree all of your comments, except this one, "You can not just set `next[some_index_depending_on value]` to `index[i]` - there would be no lists.", suppose we are doing radix sort for 21 and 31, and currently on ones. 21 will be inserted to the bucket as both head and tail, we will assign its position (0 in this case) directly bucketHead[1] and bucketTail[1], when we deal with 31 (whose position is 1, which is the value of index[1]), we should be able to assign it to the next of bucketTail,

Comment: And move bucketTail to 31. In code, it is `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = index[i]`, or 'next[bucketTail[value]] = index[i]' + `bucketTail[value]=index[i]`, which makes 21 -> 31, and 31 as tail. So, I think it is safe to not using pointTo and next. The other reason why I think it is safe to not using pointTo and next is LSD based radix sort reserves oder. What is the issue in my description? Please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: For LSD based radix sort reserves order, please refer to rcgldr's reply on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544353/most-significant-v-s-least-significant-radix-sort

Comment: (forgot to address @LinMa in my previous comment) Not quite sure I see what you are getting at. You could keep one value in `bucketHead[value]` and a 2nd in `buckettail[value]`, but where does the 3rd, 7th, umpteenth go?

Comment: Hi greybeard, I think we can use next to track the linked list. My question is not about using next, but I think using pointTo and globalPtr are useless. In your code, you do not use them, correct? :)

More specifically, I think this line `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = globalPtr` should be written as `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = index[i]`, and this line `index[ptr++] = pointTo[j]` should be written as `index[ptr++] = j;` and it is the same logic are your code. I could be wrong, and please feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: Also it is because your elegant code makes me think using an additional level of reference (by use of globalPtr and pointTo) are useless. In your example, you are just use `val`, which is the same as `index`, correct?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, greybeard. Mark your reply as answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class St {
    public static int calculate(String s){
        char[]arr=s.toCharArray();
        int length=arr.length;
        int count=length;
        for(int i=1;i<length;i++){
            int len=length-i;
            int j=0;
            for(;j<len;j++)
                if(arr[j]!=arr[j+i]){
                    break;
                }
            count+=j;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        int n=scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String s=scanner.next();
            System.out.println(calculate(s));
        }
    }
}
```

it almost passed all testcases except last two due to timeout hope my work helps happy coding..

Comment: Thanks SmashCode, how your reply related to my question? :)

Comment: there will be add comment button if you mean how i told the number of test cases passes i am hackerrank user too.

Comment: Thanks SmashCode, I think your code runs slower than SuffixArray? Your code runs O(n^2)?

Comment: Hi SmashCode, in the original code I posted, where I am especially confused by this statement, `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]] = globalPtr`, why we cannot just use `bucketTail[value] = next[bucketTail[value]]=index[i]`, not see too much values of `globalPtr`? Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.