# Why does radix sort can't bucket-sort by the most significant digit firstly

Tags: c, algorithm, radix-sort

As the title, I can't understand the erroeous sort when bucket-sort by the least significant digit firstly.

Comment: Try working through a radix sort of [12, 21] by hand.

Answer (score 1):

A most significant digit (MSD) radix sort can be used to sort keys in lexicographic order. Unlike a least significant digit (LSD) radix sort, a most significant digit radix sort won't be [stable sort](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Stable_Sort) i.e. it does not necessarily preserve the original order of duplicate keys.

An MSD radix sort stops rearranging the position of a key when the processing reaches a unique prefix of the key.

You can also see: [most significant v.s. least significant radix sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544353/most-significant-v-s-least-significant-radix-sort)